# iOS app-delegate method taking more than 17 sec

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin iOS app which has to accept audio files from other apps. For eg: it accepts audio (.mp3) file from mailing app. In the `OpenURL` method I have the function to save file and create a new entry in xml file. This task I suppose is taking longer than 17 sec and the app crashes.

There is a comment in AppDelegate.cs `// You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.`

Here is the code in AppDelegate.cs:

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
{
        return this.Upload(url).Result;
}

async public Task<bool> Upload(NSUrl SharedUri)
{
      await SomeUploadTask();
      return true;
}
```

Comment: Never played around with xamarin before but it sounds like you're blocking your app and should be running this function as an async process on another thread. Then you can return in your function within 17 secs whilst this task runs in the background. Maybe this will help https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/

Comment: @Hodson Thank you for the quick response, but I cannot await a task in openURL method, I get error: `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<bool>'` and If I make openURL async method it throws a new error.

Comment: @Arti Did you find a solution? Can you please post it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

I am not sure if this works or not.

Let's try not to block a method for more time.

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Task.Run(() => SomeUploadTask());
            return true;
        }
        private Task SomeUploadTask()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```